# Converting string to lowercase

Tags: python, string, substring

So I'm writing a basic program that counts the number of characters in a user's name and the number of times each vowel occurs. However, it only counts if the user inputs upper-case letters, but I have set it to convert the string to lower-case.

```
n = input("Please enter your name: ")
n.lower()
x = (len(n))
a = n.count('a')
e = n.count('e')
i = n.count('i')
o = n.count('o')
u = n.count('u')

print("Your name has {0} a, {1} e, {2} i, {3} o, {4} u and is {5} characters long.".format(a,e,i,o,u,x))
```

What's wrong with this?

Comment: `n = n.lower()`, not `n.lower()`.  Strings are immutable and do not change when you call their methods.

Answer (score 3):

you must assign to n; `n.lower()` does not change `n`, but returns a new string in lower case.

replace:

```
n.lower()
```

with:

```
n = n.lower()
```